# Python - Use class or modules when you share some data dictionary across functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, dictionary

I'm suffering of  *too many classes syndrome*, struggling to identify when is properly justified use a class in python.

I have a function which its code escalated very quickly up to around 350 lines of code and in order to have comprehensive tests and more control over the code itself, refactoring pop up into my mind.

Just after starting refactoring, I've split the code into several small functions but they are dependent of some variables and data dictionary that now must be passed as parameters.

The original code looks like the following :

```
def process_rooms_json(path, country, json_dict):

    # Create Dict from json_dict 
    rooms_dict = dict()
    # Create another 
    employee_dict = dict()

    list_meetings = []

    # Iterate over the folder
    for file_name in [f for f in os.listdir(path)]:

        with open(folder + '/' + file_name, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:

            # Extract contect
            set_apps = function_which_creates_list(f.read())

                for app in set_apps:
                    # Block of code which extracts certain info
                    # Block of code which build  a dictionary
                    list_meetings.append(result_of_big_code)

    return list_meetings
```

and now it's something like

```
def process_rooms_json(path, country, json_dict):

    # Create Dict from json_dict 
    rooms_dict = dict()

    # Create another 
    employee_dict = dict()

    list_meetings = []

    # Iterate over the folder
    for file_name in [f for f in os.listdir(path)]:

        with open(folder + '/' + file_name, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:

            # Extract content
            set_apps = function_which_creates_list(f.read())

                for app in set_apps:


                    # Block of code which extracts certain info

                    new_dict = do_a_lot_of_stuff_1(employee_dict, country, filename)
                    new_dict2 = do_a_lot_of_stuff_2(new_dict['some_list'])
                    new_dict3 = do_a_lot_of_stuff_3(employee_dict, country)
                    new_dict4 = do_a_lot_of_stuff_4(rooms_dict, country, file_name)
                    new_dict5 = do_a_lot_of_stuff_5(rooms_dict, employee_dict)

                    # Create result
                    return_dict = dict()
                    return_dict['some_filed'] = new_dict['another field']
                    ...

                    list_meetings.append(return_didct)
    return list_meetings
```

I'm really tempted to create a class, let say RoomProcessor, and encapsulate in self the path, json dictionaries and country code. I don't know in which extent this is correct or if I'm totally loosing the point.

In terms of maintainability, code readability and proper python idiomatic approach, is sharing same data_dictionary across "functions" proper justification to create a class ?

Comment: Well a function performs some (piece of) work while a class instance can have _state_ too. The processing part naturally operates on some input and returns an output, so this is where function parameters come into play. If your only reason to use a class is to "hide" parameters as instance variables then you probably shouldn't do that. You should rather determine whether it makes sense to have state (e.g. to access that dict later on). Otherwise you can still use a class to encapsulate the methods however they should use proper parameters. For "Pythonic" you can refer to `import this`.

Comment: As I'm not keeping any _state_ (I'm just populating a MongoDB instance) doesn't make any sense create a class. There fore I assume it's correct pass the parameters over and over programmatically speaking, isn't it ?

Comment: At least that makes the intent of the functions much more clear. On the other hand it probably doesn't harm to create a class whose instances hold onto `path, country, json_dict`, however setting other instance variables during the processing (such as `new_dict2`) can make the whole thing unclear. If `f2` operates on `self._new_dict2` and relies on `f1` begin called beforehand (in order to set that variable) then this is really not clear from the functions themselves. On the other hand if `new_dict2` was a parameter to `f2` then there is just no way to call it without that argument.

Comment: Crystal clear, thank you !